# Facebook Login problem in Angular .NET Core app in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, facebook-login, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to build a simple app using Visual Studio 2022 making use of the ASP.NET Core with Angular project template. I follow msdn instructions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

- I pick authentication type Individual accounts.
- After creating the example app I'm trying to add Facebook authentication. I configure my facebook app in facebook developer section then I add facebook authentication when configuring services. So far so good.
- I runn the app go to the login page click facebook and after loggin in via facebook I get following error:

  core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signin-facebook'
  Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signin-facebook'
- I can see in the network tab (image 4) that there's an facebook callback with authentication token, but what the issue is that I'm not being signed in to my app.

On the other hand logging in via email account works prefectly fine.

So from the error it looks as it's angular route not being defined, but actually this signin-facebook route shoould have been handled by the identity server which should have created user account in ASP.NET user identity tables.

I'd really appriciate your help in sorting this out.

Image 1: Creating app
[image: Creating App]

Image 2: Facebook authentication config:
[image: Facebook authentication config]

Image 3: Error on facebook callback
[image]

Image 4: Error callback in network tab
[image]

Comment: Can you post your middleware pipeline (`Configure` method)? Do you have the `UseAuthentication` middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. And after lots of working with the Microsoft default project I found that some steps are missing in the document.

I have just added `"/signin-facebook"` to the property `PROXY_CONFIG.context` in the file `proxy.conf.js`.

Also, I think all routes for other external authentication must be added to the path.

So after this editing and running the project, You will be redirect to the register page after authentication.